# EF5 -> EF6 strange migration behavior

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

We have an ASP.Net MVC4 project that has been using Entity Framework 5 for a year now. We just updated to Entity Framework 6 using the NuGet Package Manager and now we are getting odd behavior in the migration generation.

A Many-to-many table that existed correctly, now EF wants to add an additional column and FK... and Columns that have the `[NotMapped]` attribute are NOT being ignored. I had to use `.Ignore()`

Here is the relevent code for the Many-to-many that has been working with EF5, but suddenly doesn't want to work with EF6...

```
public class Grade
{
    [Key]
    public int GradeKey { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string GradeLevel { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int TestKey { get; set; }

    ...

    [UIHint("_GradeCheckboxes")]
    [Order(5)]
    [Display(Order = 5)]
    [DisplayName("Grades")]
    public virtual ICollection<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
}

//Fluent API for the join
modelBuilder.Entity<Grade>().HasKey(p => p.GradeKey).HasMany(p => p.Tests).WithMany(d => d.Grades).Map(x => 
{
    x.MapLeftKey("Grade_GradeKey"); 
    x.MapRightKey("Test_TestKey");
    x.ToTable("GradeTests");
});

// Migration
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.Grades", "Test_TestKey", c => c.Int()); // This is a problem
    AlterColumn("dbo.Students", "StateCode", c => c.String()); // This already exists in DB
    AlterColumn("dbo.Students", "SchoolName", c => c.String()); // This already exists in DB
    CreateIndex("dbo.Grades", "Test_TestKey"); // Problem
    CreateIndex("dbo.StudentTests", "StudentKey");
    CreateIndex("dbo.StudentTests", "TestKey"); 
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Grades", "Test_TestKey", "dbo.Tests", "TestKey"); // Problem
    AddForeignKey("dbo.StudentTests", "StudentKey", "dbo.Students", "StudentKey", cascadeDelete: true); // Already exists
    AddForeignKey("dbo.StudentTests", "TestKey", "dbo.Tests", "TestKey", cascadeDelete: true); // Already exists
}
```

Has anyone else experience this problem when upgrading or with EF6 in general. I have tried many different tactics and internet searches to try and solve this issue for a few days now. I have even removed the `__MigrationHistory` table and deleted all of the migrations and has it start fresh from the models alone, but it still wants to create the `Test_TestKey` column in the `Grades` table instead of in the Many-to-many table...

Comment: I've never used data annotations and fluent api together, and things always worked as intended for my projects that migrated from EF5 to EF6 (fluent api is better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have dropped the [Key] attribute from Grade and tested and works as expected when intialising a basic database

```
public class Grade
{
  
    public int GradeKey { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string GradeLevel { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

fluent api is the same asyours when building many to many table

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Grade>()
                    .HasKey(g => g.GradeKey)
                    .HasMany(g => g.Tests)
                    .WithMany(t => t.Grades)
                    .Map(map =>
                        {
                            map.ToTable("GradeTests");
                            map.MapLeftKey("GradeKey");
                            map.MapRightKey("TestKey");
                        });
```

Database tables

[image]